# Entity Framework Core not saving Bit Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using the same code but it's not saving this one column. The value is false and I just want to set it to true. This comes from DB First approach.

```
var reportEmail = await _context.BMTransactionEmails.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.TransactionID == 12854);

reportEmail.FgSendEmail = true;

var saved = _context.SaveChanges();
```

Here's the class

```
public partial class BMTransactionEmail
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public bool? FgSendEmail { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the context

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BMTransactionEmail>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasNoKey();

    entity.ToTable("BMTransactionEmail");
});
```

Comment: The title says EF Core while the tag says EF 6. Not a great start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging on the context, comparing the other tables, the reason it wasn't being tracked is because it didn't have a key.

Since this was scaffolded, I added another partial context class and added the block below.

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<BMTransactionEmail>()
       .HasKey(r => r.TransactionID);
}
```

This has solved the issue.

Comment: So is `TransactionID` a primary key in the db? Strange that it was scaffolded this way

Comment: It is not, there's no key defined on the Db as well.